# eingreifen und einmischen: negativ, positiv oder beide?

Tags: translation, meaning, german-to-english

In englischen Wörterbüchern sehe ich immer zwei Übersetzungen für das deutsche Wort *eingreifen*:

- intervene
- interfere

Diese zwei englischen Wörter haben ähnliche Bedeutungen: sie bedeuten etwas machen, das einen Prozess oder Entwicklung stoppt, an dem du nicht beteiligt bist.  Allerdings im amerikanischen Englisch benutzt man das Wort *interfere* fast immer in einem negativen Sinn:

- **Don't interfere with my plans!** (Ich habe Pläne und deine Aktionen, die sie stören, sind ungewollt: negativer Sinn)
- **You shouldn't interfere in other people's business.** (Wenn dich etwas nichts angeht, sollst du nichts machen: die Aktionen sind negativ)

Andererseits hat das Wort *intervene* gewöhnlich einen positiven Sinn: das ist was der Held in Märchenbüchern immer macht, um die Prinzessin zu retten.  Es impliziert, dass die Situation, die im Moment passiert, schlecht oder böse ist und dass die Aktionen die Situation verbessern werden:

- **The man tried to kill himself but his friends intervened.** (Er wird leben, weil die Aktionen seiner Freunde ihn gerettet haben: positives Ergebnis)

Auf Englisch würde man fast nie das Wort *interfere* in dem letzten Beispiel benutzen, das würde implizieren, dass der Selbstmord des Manns etwas Neutrales oder vielleicht Gutes wäre.  Wenn man *interfere* in diesem Satz benutze, könnte man vielleicht erwarten, den folgenden Satz zu lesen:

- **The man tried to kill himself but his friends interfered.  He would have to find another way to do it.** (Vielleicht ist der Mann frustriert, dass er den Selbstmord nicht begehen konnte: negatives Ergebnis)

Der Satz, wo ich diesem Wort begegnet bin:

> Seine Bemerkungen zur Empfängnisverhütung sind nach meiner
>   Einschätzung ein Signal, dass die katholische Kirche nicht überall
>   gängelnd **eingreifen** will.

Also meine Fragen:

1. Hat *eingreifen* einen solchen positiven oder negativen Sinn?  Welchen?
2. In dem Satz nach oben, könnte man auch das Wort *einmischen* benutzen?
3. Sind *eingreifen* und *einmischen* austauschbar?

Comment: Intervenieren, eingreifen, sich einmischen - das sind Verben, die sich nicht auf ein Du beschränken lassen. Auch ich kann eingreifen, er, wir, ihr, sie. Wie das derjenige bewertet, dem es geschieht, ist oft nicht vorherzusehen und die Wörter treffen darüber keine Aussage. Der, der es tut, wird es immer positiv bewerten, sonst würde er es ja nicht tun. Dritte Parteien können es wieder anders bewerten. Interferieren würde ich eher als Seiteneffekt einer anderen Handlung betrachten, während intervenieren ein zielgerichtetes Handeln ist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Eingreifen* wird verwendet, wenn der Eingreifende ein wie auch immer geartetes, größtenteils anerkanntes *Recht* auf das Eingreifen bzw. ein moralisches oder politisches Mandat oder die erforderliche Autorität dafür hat. Siehe *Eingreiftruppe*. --> to intervene

*Einmischen* dagegen bedeutet ungefragtes und (meistens) unerwünschtes Eingreifen oder gar Stören – daher gibt es auch keine *Einmischtruppe*. --> to interfere

Ob die jeweiligen Begriffe jetzt eine „positive oder negative Bedeutung“ haben? *Einmischen* kann man sich z. B. auch in eine Prügelei, um die Streithähne auseinanderzubringen – es ist dann immer noch ungefragt bzw. unaufgefordert, aber kann im Endeffekt durchaus positiv sein.

Comment: also ich würde in einem bericht, bspw. polizeibericht, eher eingreifen als einmischen erwarten. weil einmischen hat meiner meinung nach schon eine negative konotation...

Comment: Der Polizeibericht impliziert ja auch *Autorität*, daher wie gesagt da: *eingreifen*. Bei einem unbeteiligten Dritten ohne diese Autorität könnte man meinem Gefühl nach ruhig *einmischen* sagen

Comment: ich meinte auch sowas wie: bei einer gewalttätigen Auseinandersetzung zwischen zwei Personen wurde eine dritte Person verletzt, die versuchte einzugreifen.

Comment: "Der grosse Hans hat den armen kleinen Fritz verkloppt. Da konnte ich nicht anders, als mich einzumischen"

Comment: Da würde ich eher dazwischengehen sagen xD

Comment: Vermutlich kann man (zusätzlich zu den richtig beschriebenen Bedeutungsunterschieden) sagen, dass "einmischen" auch weniger förmlich ist als "eingreifen".

Comment: Der erste Absatz ist eine Contradictio in Adjecto - ein Widerspruch in sich. Wenn Eingreifen ein berechtigtes Eingreifen ist, dann gibt es auch ein unberechtigtes Eingreifen und das ist zweifellos der Fall. Darin unterscheidet es sich daher auch nicht vom Einmischen, denn auch Einmischungen finden berechtigt oder unberechtigt statt. Dass eine  Bewertung mit keinem der Begriffe einhergeht ist dagegen richtig.

Comment: @user unknown: Das ist eben der Unterschied zwischen *was einer macht* und *wie er es verkauft* - Was der eine Staat als "Einmischen in innere Angelegenheiten" *beklagt*, wird der andere als "Eingreifen im Interesse einer höheren moralischen Autorität" *verkaufen* - Sprache ist genauso logisch wie die Interessen dahinter.....

Comment: @tofro: Die Einmischung Russlands in den Fall des angeblich entführten Mädchens in Berlin würde wohl jeder, ob zustimmend oder ablehnend, als Einmischung bezeichnen, weil es ein rein sprachliches Drängen und Verlautbaren war. Als Eingriff würde das wohl kaum jmd. bezeichnen wollen, weil es keine materielle, handelnde Aktivität gab, die Ereignisse zu beeinflussen. Umgekehrt sind aber viele Eingriffe Einmischungen - chirourgische jedoch eher nicht. Einmischungen gibt es auch noch beim Marmorkuchen.

Comment: @user unknown: Russland hat intern diese Einmischung mit großer Sicherheit als ".notwendiges Eingreifen “ bezeichnet..... Das ist es, was ich sagen wollte.

Comment: Russland hat, da es ein Land ist, gar nichts behauptet. Russische Offizielle haben sich sicher primär russisch geäußert. Aber wenn Du so sicher bist wird es Dir sicher leicht fallen ein Zitat zu bringen.

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde sagen, dass der wesentliche Unterschied im Deutschen darin besteht, dass *einmischen* weniger konkret ist, das könnte auch eine reine Meinungsäußerung sein, wie in

> Da mische ich mich nicht ein!

Es schwingt außerdem etwas *viele Köche verderben den Brei* mit, also meiner Meinung nach ein negativer Beigeschmack, aber nicht stark ausgeprägt.

Bei der diplomatischen Wendung *Einmischung in innere Angelegenheiten* wird deutlich, dass es nur um Wortmeldung geht, etwa öffentlich Forderungen zu stellen.

Eingreifen ist (wie am Wortstamm erkennbar) deutlich handlungsorientiert.